# In Ubuntu 20.04.3 sudo su or any other command not working

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

```
yashm@yashm-Inspiron-15-3567:~$ sudo su
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

Comment: what is the output of `which sudo` and `echo $PATH`?

Comment: You seem to have replaced `sudo` or `su` with a Python script.

Comment: Or maybe there's something in root's `.bashrc` that runs a Python script.

Comment: @ti7 Don't use `which`, use `type`.

Comment: that's my suspicion too .. ahah - certainly better here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the fix myself
as sudo command doesn't work you will have to have synaptic package manager installed before hand
search for python3-apt mark it for complete removal and reinstall it completely everything would be normal again
refer :https://www.datasciencelearner.com/importerror-no-module-named-apt_pkg-fix/